# OpenCv use exp with Mat

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to perform a Matrix calculation in OpenCV according to this formula:

```
newMat = 1 / ( 1 + exp( scalar * ( otherScalar - Matrix ) ) )
```

Is there an easy way to do this in OpenCV or do I have to calculate this in a for loop?
The main problem for me is the exp( Matrix ).

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maecky's answer is perfectly fine - for 1-channel images.

The fun starts if your image has more than one channel. For some reasons,

```
float(scalar) - _3ChannelMat
```

applies the operation only on the first channel, while multiplication

```
float(scalar2) * _3channelMat
```

is done on all the channels of the image. Funny, isn't it?

The solution is to use cv::Scalars:

```
newMat = cv::Scalar(0.4, 0.4, 0.4) * ( cv::Scalar(255, 255, 255) - _3channelMat);
```

I have filed a bug a while ago on this strange behaviour, but no answer yet.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. In my case i just need one channel but it's good to know - just in case.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, i found the answer myself, here the code if someone has the same problem:

```
newMat = float(scalar) * ( float(otherScalar) - newMat);
cv::exp( newMat, newMat );
newMat= 1.0f / ( 1.0f + newMat);
```

Comment: 1.0f / Mat does element-wise division. If that is not what you want -- and your mat formula in the question is quite familiar to me --, check my answer for the correct expression.

Answer (score 0):

@Maecky the chances are you just wrote a bug in your answer.

*`1+A` usually means `I+A`* and 1/A means inversion (that is A^{-1}) where `I` is the identity matrix -- called eye in matlab and in opencv. (Moreover F/A === F*A^{-1})

In your solution you are adding an all-one matrix to `newMat` (called ones in matlab and in opencv), not eye.

Correctly (that is calculating (I + exp(scalar*(otherScalar*I-Matrix)))^{-1} ):

```
using namespace cv;
Size s = Matrix.size();
int t = Matrix.type();
Mat newMat;
Mat I = Mat::eye(s,t);

exp( scalar * ( otherScalar*I - Matrix ), newMat );
newMat = (I + newMat).inv();
```